# Im missing some global variables

Tags: java, android

I've got 2 activities and a class that extends Application where I'm trying to store global variables with a kind of setter getter functions.

The main activity sets some views and a chart; then calls the second activity which should be setting values to be used afterwards on the previous chart.

Then pressing backbutton and returning to the previous activity onRestart is called and the chart is refreshed.

The problem is I lose my theorically global variables somewhere. Debugging i realized that the functions work perfectly fine while im adding values in the second activity but when I return to the first activity `globalXCount` returns '0' again. Why is that?

I think im missunderstanding some point regarding lifecycles.
I attach some fragments of the code.

First activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Global glObj = new Global();
CombinedChart mChart;
private int itemcount;
float displayed;
private final List<String> mMonthList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    itemcount = ((Global) this.getApplication()).getGlobalXCount();
    displayed =  itemcount/20;
    mChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.mchart);
    populateHeaderList();
    setChartSettings();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QandA.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    itemcount = ((Global) this.getApplication()).getGlobalXCount();
    displayed =  itemcount/20;
    populateHeaderList();
    setChartSettings();
}
```

Second activity:

```
public class QandA extends Activity {

Global glObj = new Global();
ViewFlipper flipper;
private float lastX;

...

               }else{
                    //TODO If all information if correctly filled
                    trainedmins = et1.getText().toString();
                    localLineValue = Integer.parseInt(trainedmins) * Integer.parseInt(statusQ1);

                    //Add values to lines
                    glObj.setLineXvalues(localLineValue);

                    // TODO Add new Bar value //

                    //Add 1 more value to count
                    glObj.addGlobalXCount();

                }

...
```

Global class:

```
public class Global extends Application {

//TODO

public Integer globalXCount;
private List<Integer> lineXvalues = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Integer> barXvalues = new ArrayList<>();

//////
public Integer getGlobalXCount() {
    if (this.globalXCount == null){
        this.globalXCount = 0;
        return this.globalXCount;
    }else{
        return this.globalXCount;
    }
}

public void addGlobalXCount() {
    if (this.globalXCount == null){
        this.globalXCount = 0;
    }else{
        this.globalXCount = this.globalXCount + 1;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: obviously `glObj` != `((Global) this.getApplication())`

Comment: If you use setters and getters (sigh!), then the field must be private. Otherwise, you don't need them, because it's already accessible. Simply use `Global.globalXCount` to reference your global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, register your custom Application context in AndroidManifest.xml within the `<application>`-tag.

```
<application
  android:name="<your_package>.Global" ...>
```

Access the global application context within your activities like this:

```
Global glObj = (Global) getApplicationContext();
glObj.addGlobalXCount();
```

Do not create a new instance with `new`! Always retrieve the instance via `getApplicationContext()`.

Furthermore, I would suggest you to initialize your class field `glObj` within the `onCreate()`-method of your Activities.